# MySQL GROUP BY slow across three tables with spatial search

Tags: mysql

I am adding some further First World War records to my astreetnearyou.org site

I have three tables:

- people - contains full details of over 1 million people who died
- addresses - contains about 700,000 different addresses for about 600,000 of these people
- cemeteries - a new table which has records of about 15,000 cemeteries;

In terms of relationships, every address has the ID of the person it relates to; every person in the people table has the name of the cemetery they are buried in (as an aside, these can be long varchar values, would it be better to give them unique integer IDs for the join? Answer: I tried it and it shaved about 0.5 secs off the query time)

I want to run a query that essentially says "give me a unique list of all the people who lived or are buried in this map area (bounding box)"

An example query is:

```
SELECT people.id, people.rank, people.forename, `people`.surname, people.regiment, people.date_of_death, people.cemeteryname, cemeteries.country, cemeteries.link 
FROM people
JOIN cemeteries ON people.cemeteryId=cemeteries.id 
LEFT JOIN addresses ON addresses.personId=people.id 
WHERE MBRContains( GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(-0.35 51.50,-0.32 51.51)' ), cemeteries.point) OR MBRContains( GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(-0.35 51.50,-0.32 51.51)' ), addresses.point)
GROUP BY people.id
```

This returns 276 results but takes about 6 seconds. Without the GROUP BY it's 296 results including the duplicate IDs but takes well under a second.  If I remove the LEFT JOIN table and associated WHERE clause (so I only get matches by cemetery, not address) it is also very quick.

I have spatial indexes on both point fields and all the fields that are in the JOIN conditions, plus based on another post on here I've added indexes across the id and point fields in the addresses table, and the cemetery and point fields in the cemeteries table.

I'm no sql expert so any advice on making this more efficient and thereby quicker would be much appreciated. Also I guess some more table info would probably be of use, but can you tell me what would be helpful and how to produce it?!

Comment: have you indexes  on the tables ??

Comment: make sure to run `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`  first before continueing to ask for performance.. As that is not the way how you would write ANSI Standards SQL 92 confirm queries with `GROUP BY`..

Comment: @scaisEdge yes, spatial indexes on the point data and standard indexes on all the fields that are in the joins and group

Comment: This is how you should use [GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975951/mysql-group-by-slow-across-three-tables-with-spatial-search) in MySQL, note your query can be valid with [functionally dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) make sure to have atleast MySQL 5.7.5.. if not valid your query will select unrelating data for each column in the select which is not in the group by which means a invalid resultset. .

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tried the first option but believe it was already set by default and has made no difference. I have also now updated the query to explicitly reference table names, but I am not sure if that's what you meant? Also, was your first link intended to go to an external resource? Apologies for my ignorance here, certainly a MySQL novice!

Comment: *" Also, was your first link intended to go to an external resource? Apologies for my ignorance here"* the link was meant to go here [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), i think i mis copy paste it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you. Having read that I can see that my query requires ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to be off, but as per the documentation that is fine in terms of the results I get because all the fields not in the GROUP BY will return the exact same values. But does it have a big impact on performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE people ADD INDEX IdCemIdIdx (id, cemeteryId);
```

if possible, use: 
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html